# How to Swap Partition Size For Domestic Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swap

Trying here to do an installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, focusing on domestic surveillance with some ip cameras.

There will be about 12 cameras, which we are going to add in Zoneminder with images capture function.

With this in mind, what should be the Swap partition size?

And how may one enable this partition and start using it?

I already have an installation system with 5GB of Swap, but heard that it isn't enough.

Comment: Start with something big. Then shrink it (if you thing that you will need the space). When you are settled on a size, then grow other partition to use the spare space.

Comment: Is it recommendable to resize partitioning?

I've never had good experience doing it.

Comment: Backup first. It can be done. You have to take the file-systems offline first.

Comment: The Ubiquity https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity installer used by Ubuntu 18.04 now defaults to no swap partition, and instead generates a swap file which is automatically generated and enabled. It has done so since late 2017, when the kernel improved swap file performance. Therefore, you don't have to create a swap partition, and can monitor your system to determine how much swap is really needed. You can increase or decrease swap file size and use ('swappiness' https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness ) without going offline and rebooting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, I wouldn't overengineer this situation. Of course, there're different scenarios and for each of them, you might want a different size of swap, but for normal needs you might have at home, you can stick to this recommendation by Red Hat: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-disk-partitioning-setup-x86#sect-recommended-partitioning-scheme-x86 (table 8.3, you need to scroll a bit).

Having said that, start with finding out how much RAM you have.

Another discussion about the same topic from 2013 is on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap You might want to read through it.

As for the second question. If you install the system, you don't really need to do anything else to start using it. The system (Ubuntu) will use your swap automatically whenever runs out of RAM.

Comment: That table dose not even describe a continues function.

Comment: My `# swapon --show` command output shows 0b in USED column, so that is right?

Swap partition would only be used when RAM memory is depleted?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Swap partitions are absolutely needed only for those who use Hibernation; a swap file in /home or /var is just as fast nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

For a 1Tb HDD, I'd recommend the following partitioning:

`/    <== primary partition, 10gb root partition with **boot flag**
/usr  <== logical partition, 24gb read-only user data
/var  <== logical partition, 26gb variable files
swap  <== logical partition, 11gb used when psysical RAM memory is full
/tmp  <== logical partition, 12gb temporary files
/home <== logical partition, 400gb home directories
the rest <== free space`

It is similar to the I've been user for some time, and have had satisfatory results.

Notice the differents sizes, for quicker recognizing.

Comment: Aren't there any more partitions I could add?

Comment: This is part of Linux File Hierarchy Structure.

Those option for specific partitioning are provided during Ubuntu or Debian instalation process.

Comment: Swap partitions are absolutely needed only for those who use Hibernation; a swap file in /home or /var is just as fast nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would suggest a lighter desktop than GNOME, as one of our [PLUG](https://www.pdxlinux.org/) members had problems with a 12 camera Zoneminder install last week. I'd try [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/what-is-ubuntu-mate/)*, [Xubuntu](https://docs.xubuntu.org/current/user/C/what-is-xubuntu.html), or [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/bionic-3-released/) (all 18.04.3 versions).

- He found success with Ubuntu MATE after failing with standard Ubuntu.

Let the default install set up a swap file, then monitor it (you know how) with [swapon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/swapon.8.html), and if swapping increases, consider using swapoff and swapon to increase the swap file space.

Swap partitions are absolutely needed only for those who use Hibernation, not for users of Sleep. Used to be, swap files were slower than swap partitions; that was fixed in 2017, and swap files are just as fast, plus easier to manage if you should find you need more swap space because of a particular app later on.

Also, I would suggest [dialing down the amount of swapping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness) to [10-15](https://haydenjames.io/linux-performance-almost-always-add-swap-space/).

Comment: Isn't KDE lighter then those you suggested?

Comment: MATE works, and MATE is generally accepted as being lighter than KDE. Therefore, I cited the flavour which worked and the two others lighter than it was. Could have absolutely nothing to do with memory and CPU consumption, but I'm trying to make sure advice is useful.